# Drop a column from a Big Table

Tags: mysql, innodb

I need to drop a column from a big table (about 20 GB) in a production MySQL database, 
but I don't want the MySQL server to hang or make a risk on production database.

This table is using the InnoDB engine and it contains around 10,000,000 records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best possible way as far as I know, is to use a [MASTER-MASTER setup](http://www.simplicidade.org/how-to/mysql-master-master/) in mysql

You can modify MASTER1 first, and just use MASTER2 in production. Then you switch over and do the same.